# AZURE SQL Database Dynamic Ip address

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I have an Azure SQL Database and my clients want to access it. They belong to a place where they are assigned new IP every time whenever they turn on PC/Internet.
I have tried to assign a range to access it but they have a huge range gap, for eg 35.111.111.0 to 199.255.255.255,  and If I assign it full range access it will be highly insecure.
Please guide me if there are some permissions or solutions I can use for this scenario.

Comment: Please ask database admin related question on the dedicated DBA sister site of SO!

Answer (score 0):

You can set IP address range from which communications are allowed into SQL Database in the Azure SQL Database firewall but for stable IP addresses, this strategy is acceptable.

A firewall security feature called virtual network rules determines whether communications from certain `subnets` in virtual networks are accepted by the server for your databases and elastic pools in Azure SQL Database.

For dynamic IP addresses to establish and to manage connection from a specific subnet the `Virtual Network Rule` can be easier substitute.

**References:**
[IP vs. Virtual network firewall rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/network-access-controls-overview?view=azuresql#ip-vs-virtual-network-firewall-rules)

[virtual network service endpoints and rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/vnet-service-endpoint-rule-overview?view=azuresql)